# Unable to install Manjaro along with Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, manjaro

My PC is in UEFI mode with GPT partitioning. I have created a Manjaro bootable usb drive using Rufus in Windows. When I go to the boot menu and select the usb drive, it gives me the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: No, I want to install Manjaro. But I'm unable to, because when I go to the boot menu and select the usb drive, it gives me this error.

Comment: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/manjarolinux/release/17.0.6/gnome/manjaro-gnome-17.0.6-stable-x86_64.iso?r=https%3A%2F%2Fmanjaro.org%2Fget-manjaro%2F&ts=1510647035&use_mirror=excellmedia

Answer (score 0):

I think your USB disk hasn't been written properly. Linux prefer xfs or some ext file system whereas windows prefer NTFS. So, while writing USB disks in windows this may happens.

Try writing the USB disk from image in a Linux system as follows.

1. Plugin the USB in a running Linux system. Format it using GParted or any other tools in `ext3` file system.
2. **Then Unmount the disk** using `sudo umount -f /dev/sdX` (**Replace X** with your USB device's filename in /dev/sdX)
3. Download the Manjaro image in running Linux system. Use the following command to burn it in USB device.

   ```
    sudo dd if=/path_to_image of=/dev/sdX
   ```

   Replace `/path_to_image` with path of the image file.

   If you want to monitor progress of the above process install `pv` and use the following.

   ```
   sudo dd if=/path_to_image |pv| of=/dev/sdX
   ```

Now try using the newly written USB to boot.

If you stick to use windows to burn the disk image you may consider `unetbootin` tool to burn the disk image. It's well-known but 100% success not guranted.

Comment: Etcher got the job done. However, I tried unetbootin before that and it didn't work. Anyways, thanks for your answer.